# BASH: How to copy the name of the file and insert it into the text using script?

Tags: linux, bash, copy, ubuntu-14.04, paste

So I need to create a lot of text files.

Each of the text file is named AAAAA.txt, BBBBB.txt, CCCCC.txt and etc etc. 
Within each text file, all the content is as follows:

1.Copy "to-be-replaced".txt into the folder EXCLUSIVE.

2.Copy the gs file to replace the existing gs file.

3.The .projectdata should also be copied to the correct path.

So, I need to write a script, that copies the name of the file (AAAAA, BBBBB, and so on) and then place it in the "to-be-replaced" within its content.

How can I do that? need some idea please.

Thank you~~
MT32

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a HERE document which expands variables if the delimiter isn't quoted:

```
#!/bin/bash
for char in {A..Z} ; do
    filename=$char$char$char$char$char.txt
    cat <<EOF > $filename
1.Copy $filename into the folder EXCLUSIVE.

2.Copy the gs file to replace the existing gs file.

3.The .projectdata should also be copied to the correct path.

EOF
done
```

Comment: I didnt spell out my problems accurately but I managed to follow your sample and used string instead of char, and it worked perfectly except for one problem:
#!/bin/bash
for string in cellanddungeon aircraftsimulator FIFAsample ; do
filename=$string
cat<<EOF >"$filename".txt
1.Copy access_$filename_200601.exe into the folder EXCLUSIVE
2.Copy the gs file to replace the existing gs file.
3.The .projectdata should also be copied to the correct path.

The resultant filename is okay, but the first line becomes:
1.Copy access_.exe into the folder EXCLUSIVE

Any tips to fix that problem?

Comment: `_` is a valid variable name part. Use `${filename}_200601`.